# How to echo script in php

Tags: php

I am using the shortcode execute plugin in wordpress.

This simply allows me to write shortcode like this [email_spamproof]

But I am trying to echo a script. Please see below...

```
<?php

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- 
    // spam protected email
    emailE=("enquiries@" + "example.co.uk")
    document.write('<a title="E-mail Example" href="mailto:' + emailE + '">' + emailE + '</a>')
     //-->
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <span class="spam-protected">Email address protected by JavaScript. Please enable JavaScript.</span>
    </noscript>';

?>
```

Now you can probably see my problem already.

Usually when I echo stuff it goes like this... `echo 'hello';`

And you break the string using the same apostrophes
- like this...
 `echo 'hello ' . php_name() . ' and friends'`

**My Problem**

The script also uses a similar method by adding script variables into the string, but these script apostrophes will get confused as PHP apostrophes, and break the echoed string.

How can I avoid this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The right code:

```
<?php

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    <!-- 
    // spam protected email
    emailE=('enquiries@' + 'example.co.uk')
    document.write('<a title='E-mail Example' href='mailto:' + emailE + ''>' + emailE + '</a>')
     //-->
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <span class='spam-protected'>Email address protected by JavaScript. Please enable JavaScript.</span>
    </noscript>";

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `\` character is the escape character. Prepend one to each internal use of the character used to delimit the string.

Alternatively, use a [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the escape character.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy. Save your javascript code in a new one file and then use this to load it:

```
include('myjavascript.php');
```

Then you will use the `include` option as a `echo` because the web will understand your code as HTML and you execute it when you want with `php` (like `echo`).

Answer (score 0):

You could write " in your javasript code, and then only use single quotes(') in your php echo.

A **more suitable** method is to use escape characters in your javascript code "**\'**" (without the double quotes)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape them and then concatenate the variables :

(Also I dont know if you realize, but you are echoing a commented out section of javascript)

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">    
  <!--      // spam protected email     
  emailE=("enquiries@" + "example.co.uk")     
  document.write(\'<a title="E-mail Example" href="mailto:'.emailE.'">'.emailE.'</a>\')      
  //-->     
  </script>     
  <noscript>         
  <span class="spam-protected">Email address protected by JavaScript. Please enable JavaScript.</span>     
  </noscript>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either escape them with a back slash: `echo 'It\'s cold';` or use `heredoc`:

```
echo <<<END
lots of text here
END;
```