# Echoing a bash from script

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hey so I'll try and make this as straightforward as possible while explaining what I'm trying to do.
So on a certain website that is ran like a chat room has profile pages that allows its users to do some html coding to design it. I'm trying to have php echo the visitors name. After looking at the source code for a bit I found this.

```html
<script id="id" type="type" >
    {
        "me": {
            "sessId": ######,
            "charId": ######,
            "acctId": #####,
            "name": "My users name",
            "csrf": "a lot of stuff",
            "settings": {"hideEyecons":false,"nameDing":true,"enableSound":true,"nameDingPatterns":[],"clearWhisper":true,"autoHoverGroups":true,"enableTicker":true,"autoHoverWhispers":true}
        },
        "ses": {
            "roomId": #,
            "status": "away",
            "ignored": {},
            "highlighted": {},
            "props": {}
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Is it possible to use html or php code to echo the name?

Comment: How should we be able to tell you if html markup inside that name attribute is accepted by the site or not? Why don't you simply try it? Either it is accepted or it is stripped out.

Comment: I, as a website operator, certainly would _not_ allow anyone to use markup inside user submitted content, since that opens a lot of security issues. But it isi not my web site...

Answer (score 0):

It came to my attention that I was trying to echo sessions and not javascript. 
[How to echo script in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845159/how-to-echo-script-in-php)
Is the link to a much more accurate question to what I was looking for.